# ¿Como ejecutar la misma función con un checkbox y un input text de una tabla dinamica, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Buen día, actualmente genero una tabla dinamica de esta forma:

```
var formas_pagos = $('.formas_pagos');
                    $.each(response.data, function(index,value){
                        $('<tr>')
                            .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td nombrePago').text(value.forma_pago))
                            .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td cantPago').text(value.disponible.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,')))
                            .append('<div class="cod_forma_pago" style="display:none">' + value.cod_forma_pago + '</div>')
                            .append('<div class="cod_banco" style="display:none">' + value.Cod_Banco + '</div>')
                            .append('<div class="monto_pago" style="display:none">' + value.monto_pago + '</div>')
                            .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td')
                                .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content')
                                            .append('<input type="checkbox" name="tipo_pago" class="tipo_pago" value="' + value.disponible + '"/>')
                                            .append($('<span/>').addClass('item-media').append('<i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>'))))
                            .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell')
                                                .append('<input type="number" name="cantidad" class="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad">'))
                            .appendTo(formas_pagos);
                    });
```

Dicha tabla dinamica contiene checkbox `class="tipo_pago"`, al seleccionar un checkbox ejecuto la siguiente función:

```
 $('.formas_pagos').on('click','.tipo_pago', function(e){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            let tipo_pago           = $(this).closest('tr');
            let valor_pago          = tipo_pago.find('.tipo_pago').val();
            let nombrePago          = tipo_pago.find('.nombrePago').text();
            let cantPago            = tipo_pago.find('.cantPago').text();
            let cant_ingresada_pago = tipo_pago.find('.cantidad').text();
            let cod_forma_pago      = tipo_pago.find('.cod_forma_pago').text();
            let cod_banco           = tipo_pago.find('.cod_banco').text();
            console.log("CODIGO FORMA DE PAGO: "+cod_forma_pago);


            // monto = esta variable llevara el valor a ingresar o sumar segun lo que se deba cancelar
            $$('.formas_pagos_seleccionados > tr').remove();
            let formas_pagos_seleccionados = $('.formas_pagos_seleccionados');

            console.log("SE AGREGO LA FORMA DE PAGO");
            total_forma_pago += parseFloat(valor_pago);
            let resultado = total_pagar-total_forma_pago

            if (resultado<0){
                console.log("Excedio del pago");
            }
            else{
                if (resultado===0){
                    console.log("Cubre la deuda");
                }
                else{
                    console.log("RESTA DE TOTAL A PAGAR - LA FORMA DE PAGO: "+resultado.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'));
                    console.log("TOTAL DE PAGO: "+total_forma_pago.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'));
                    $('<tr class="pagos"/>')
                        .append($('<td>/').addClass('nuevo-td')
                            .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-radio item-content').text(nombrePago)))
                        .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(cantPago))
                        .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell').append('<button value="' + cantPago + '" type="button" class="eliminarformaPago button button-fill button-raised button-circle" title="Comment"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>'))
                        .appendTo(formas_pagos_seleccionados);
                //agregarformaPago(idPedido, cod_forma_pago, monton, cod_banco, fecha, numero_documento, autorizacion, cod_cliente);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            console.log("Deschequeado");
            total_forma_pago -=parseFloat(total_forma_pago);
            console.log("TOTAL DE PAGO: "+total_forma_pago);
        }
        //e.preventDefault();
    });
```

El problema que quiero resolver es que al ingresar una cantidad en el input `class="cantidad"` ejecute la misma función anterior y realizar las mismas validaciones con el valor que obtengo de los check, con el valor que ingreso en el input.
De esta forma queda visualmente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con jQuery puedes tener multiples selectores y multiples eventos en cada handler.  Puedes ejecutar la misma funcion con este codigo, pero tendras que cambiar la funcion un poco:

```js
var total_forma_pago = 0;
var response = {data: [{forma_pago: "cheque", disponible: 12, cod_forma_pago: 1, Cod_Banco: 1, monto_pago: 10.50}]};
var formas_pagos = $('.formas_pagos');
                    $.each(response.data, function(index,value){
                        $('<tr>')
                            .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td nombrePago').text(value.forma_pago))
                            .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td cantPago').text(value.disponible.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,')))
                            .append('<div class="cod_forma_pago" style="display:none">' + value.cod_forma_pago + '</div>')
                            .append('<div class="cod_banco" style="display:none">' + value.Cod_Banco + '</div>')
                            .append('<div class="monto_pago" style="display:none">' + value.monto_pago + '</div>')
                            .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td')
                                .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content')
                                            .append('<input type="checkbox" name="tipo_pago" class="tipo_pago" value="' + value.disponible + '"/>')
                                            .append($('<span/>').addClass('item-media').append('<i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>'))))
                            .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell')
                                                .append('<input type="number" name="cantidad" class="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad">'))
                            .appendTo(formas_pagos);
                    });

 $('.formas_pagos').on('click change','.tipo_pago, .cantidad', function(e){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            let tipo_pago           = $(this).closest('tr');
            let valor_pago          = tipo_pago.find('.tipo_pago').val();
            let nombrePago          = tipo_pago.find('.nombrePago').text();
            let cantPago            = tipo_pago.find('.cantPago').text();
            let cant_ingresada_pago = tipo_pago.find('.cantidad').text();
            let cod_forma_pago      = tipo_pago.find('.cod_forma_pago').text();
            let cod_banco           = tipo_pago.find('.cod_banco').text();
            console.log("CODIGO FORMA DE PAGO: "+cod_forma_pago);


            // monto = esta variable llevara el valor a ingresar o sumar segun lo que se deba cancelar
            $('.formas_pagos_seleccionados > tr').remove();
            let formas_pagos_seleccionados = $('.formas_pagos_seleccionados');

            console.log("SE AGREGO LA FORMA DE PAGO");
            total_forma_pago += parseFloat(valor_pago);
            let resultado = total_pagar-total_forma_pago

            if (resultado<0){
                console.log("Excedio del pago");
            }
            else{
                if (resultado===0){
                    console.log("Cubre la deuda");
                }
                else{
                    console.log("RESTA DE TOTAL A PAGAR - LA FORMA DE PAGO: "+resultado.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'));
                    console.log("TOTAL DE PAGO: "+total_forma_pago.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'));
                    $('<tr class="pagos"/>')
                        .append($('<td>/').addClass('nuevo-td')
                            .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-radio item-content').text(nombrePago)))
                        .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(cantPago))
                        .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell').append('<button value="' + cantPago + '" type="button" class="eliminarformaPago button button-fill button-raised button-circle" title="Comment"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>'))
                        .appendTo(formas_pagos_seleccionados);
                //agregarformaPago(idPedido, cod_forma_pago, monton, cod_banco, fecha, numero_documento, autorizacion, cod_cliente);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            console.log("Deschequeado");
            total_forma_pago -=parseFloat(total_forma_pago);
            console.log("TOTAL DE PAGO: "+total_forma_pago);
        }
        //e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<table class="formas_pagos"></table>
```